# How do I know which modules to include when packaging with py2app?

Tags: py2app

I'm trying to package the Mac version of an open source application that I didn't write (I'm not much of a coder).  I'm using py2app 0.6.4.  The application builds on my system properly, but I'm unsure of what to list for the *includes* in the *setup.py* file.

The dependencies include qt4, PyQt, matplotlib, cherrypy, and sip.

When I looked at [this article on handling PyQt applications](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/building-mac-os-x-applications-py2app/), I noticed the dependencies were not listed simply as *PyQt* but rather *PyQt4._qt* etc.  How can I determine what to insert in the *includes* statement from the code of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When py2app runs, it's going to look at each of your scripts, automatically grabbing any modules or packages imported by your scripts. In many cases, this will suffice and you won't need to list anything in the *includes* variable. Some packages have extra files such as data files that aren't used by the `import` statement, but must be present for the package to run correctly. Then you need to explicitly include it so py2app will grab it as well. Try to use your app; if you get an error that some module or file isn't found then worry about putting it in the *includes* variable.